# Log RuntimeException thrown from thread created by Spring via the @Async annotation

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, exception, logging

I'm having some difficulty logging RuntimeException from a thread. My system is: Java 7 (b118), Spring 3.0.5. The threads are not created by hand, but via Spring's @Async annotation, which creates it's own executor behind the scenes, so I don't really have the option of overriding any methods of the thread, FutureTask or anything low level. 
So my question is if Spring has any support or if there are any best practices for handling (logging) these type of exceptions?
Any suggestions are appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: 0 accepted answers out of 5 questions. Fix that ;)

Comment: 5 Questions isn't that many...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like both [`AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) and [`<task:annotation-driven>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) can be supplied with a custom `Executor`, so you can configure logging via `ThreadFactory`.